# How to send Microsoft .docx file from Angular to Python backend without breaking it?

Tags: python, angular, flask, python-docx

I am using `python-docx` library to open and read the .docx file in Python. ***When I send the example.docx from Postman, as a file (form-data), the Python code is able to get it without saving, read the content, and send it to `Document()` class as a binary without any problem.***

However, when I try to send the binary content from Angular, then save it as a file, or directly pass through the binary to the `Document()` class. I am getting an error.

error:

```
raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

The code sample to send the blob in Angular:

```
private static example(data: ArrayBuffer): FormData {
const formdata: FormData = new FormData();
const blob: Blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' });
formdata.append('file', blob);
return formdata;
```

The code to retrieve from Python with flask:

```
file = request.files['file']
return file.read()
```

I use file.read()'s result to create a source stream for `Document()` class. The problem is this code works, as I use Postman and select any .docx file, it parses through it. Why not the angular code? It is binary data as well.

I tried to add:

```
const file: File = new File([blob], 'example.docx', {
  type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
});
```

Saving the file before actually sending it to `Document()` did not help either. When I save it, I can see that the format is broken. (different fonts etc.) How can I fix this issue?

Comment: how do you convert to ArrayBuffer ? have your tried looking at your blob after you created it by calling URL.createObjectURL(blob) is it still good before it's sent out ?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting and comparing the raw request from postman vs the raw request from angular. if you have could you please add that to your OP.

Comment: @ihorbond I converted the blob to URL with your command but in localhost, I get a 404 error when I try to access it.

@AkibRhast I do not know how to do it. However, I checked the HTTP generated code version of the request in Postman, and `----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="/C:/location/example.docx"
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`. It seems the same to me. Also, If I save the document via Python then change the document font and re-save it, it also works.

Comment: The problem is solved, It was the way I convert to ArrayBuffer, as @ihorbond stated. This was not needed at all. I just set the file that I retrieved from the cloud. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got figured out